# Why would you assign volatile to local variable before returning

Tags: java, android, android-livedata, volatile

While looking at the implementation of android LiveData, I stumbled on the following code snippet

```
public T getValue() {
        Object data = mData;
        if (data != NOT_SET) {
            return (T) data;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Why would one assign a class member to a local variable before returning it? My guess is it is related to the fact that `mData` is `volatile`, but I can't fully understand why couldn't we just `return mData`.

Comment: If this were written `if (mData != NOT_SET) { return (T) mData; }`, then the value of `mData` could be modified by another thread between the `if` and the `return`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We want to return `mData`, except if it's equal to `NOT_SET` because then we want to return `null`. Imagine if it were naively written like this:

```
    public T getValue() {
        if (mData != NOT_SET) {
            return (T) mData;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The problem is that there is no synchronization at all, so by reading `mData` twice, we create a race condition. What if the following sequence of events happens?

1. `mData` contains some value that's not `NOT_SET`, so `mData != NOT_SET` passes and we enter the `if` block.
2. Another thread comes along and sets `mData = NOT_SET;`.
3. The first thread, now inside the `if` block, returns `(T) mData`, which is `NOT_SET`. But the caller expected `null` in this case!

In fact this can happen whether or not `mData` is `volatile`. The `volatile` keyword just makes it [more likely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/106641/14637).

Comment: the race condition is there with or without `volatile`, just that reading that `mData` into a _local_ field, means that you do not care if `mData` has now changed. You reference is local, un-effected by that change. Besides, instead of doing _two_ volatile reads, you are now doing just one. I think you said the same thing in your answer, right? I am not sure that was your point